# Inbuilt richtextox shortcuts

Tags: .net, richtextbox, richedit

I once discovered an overview of inbuilt richtextbox shortcuts somewhere on microsoft.com website, but I can't find it. It contained useful hotkeys, like Ctrl+Shift+L for switching bullet style.

Where can I find a list of inbuilt richtextbox shortcuts?

(I need to know the hotkey for changing line spacing.)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx#rich_edit_shortcut_keys